# density across space (or spatial smoothing) in python/geopandas

Tags: python, geospatial, spatial, smoothing, geopandas

I'm plotting presence/absence of an entity across a lat/long coordinate grid. I'd like to transform this from a 1/0 point map to something that gives density within a given radius size for each point. I guess one way to conceptualize this is as a spatial smoothing problem. Does anyone have recommendations on how to do this efficiently in Python/Geopandas?  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I believe `geoplot` is what you are looking for. You can use `geoplot.kdeplot` which is using Kernel Density Estimate to do the spatial smoothing. It is based on GeoPandas GeoDataFrame, so you should be able to plot it directly.

Look at the documentation here: https://residentmario.github.io/geoplot/plot_references/plot_reference.html#kdeplot There is a plenty of examples how to use it.

Comment: The organization of the documentation has changed and this link has unfortunately gone stale. Here's an updated working link: https://residentmario.github.io/geoplot/plot_references/plot_reference.html#kdeplot